# Java stream sorted() behavior is depending on next takeWhile() calling

Tags: java, jvm, java-stream

I was practicing stream. Then got this strange behavior. I can't figure out the reason. That's why asking for help.

I wrote this:

```
IntStream.iterate(10, i -> i - 2)
            .limit(5)
            .sorted()
            .takeWhile(i -> i > 2)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is giving me nothing in the console, which is expected. When I am seeing the stream chain in IntelliJ IDEA, getting this:

[image]

So, after the execution of **sorted()** it is returning only one element (that element is 2 in the image) to the pipeline.

Now I commented the **takeWhile()** call. Like this:

```
IntStream.iterate(10, i -> i - 2)
            .limit(5)
            .sorted()
        //    .takeWhile(i -> i > 2)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is also printing in the console as expected(from 10 to 2 with a difference of 2).

But problem is, this time **sorted()** returned 5 elements to pipeline. When I am seeing the stream chain in IntelliJ IDEA, getting this:

[image]

My question is, why the difference is seen in calling **sorted()**? If there is a **takeWhile()** after **sorted()** then it is returning one element. If I am commenting **takeWhile()**, **sorted()** is returning stream of 5 elements.

Is JVM doing anything here for achieving better performance?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Stream.sorted()` is a stateful operation, so it is actually maintaining the `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]` state. **However, it will only send 1 item at a time**.

So, Initially it will send 1 entry: `'2'` to `takeWhile` operator which can then reject the entry and stop the stream chain. That is why you are seeing sorted returning only `2` to `takeWhile` operator.

But, when sorted is not present, `takeWhile` will get `10` as the entry. And as the condition is true, stream will continue until `takeWhile` receives `2`.

Edit:
When `takeWhile` is not present, you are getting all 5 items as output because you have 5 items in stream chain and there is no `takeWhile` to stop the stream chain.

In Intellij's Stream Trace, On the right side of sorted you are seeing how many elements are being passed to next operator after performing `sorted()` operation.

In the first case, only 1 element is being passed to `takeWhile()` as `takeWhile()` is terminating the stream chain after receiving `'2'`. But in the second case all the elements are being passed to `forEach`.

Comment: Will you check your last para? sorted() is always there. I commented takeWhile() in second code. @THe_strOX

Comment: If there is no `takeWhile` then you will get all the 5 items. Maybe I am not understanding your question but I think you are overthinking on this one.

Comment: Thanks man, I got your point after last edit. I am accepting your answer.